# Manipulate photo in a ImageView(?) and then return that picture

Tags: java, android, bitmap, android-imageview

I'm trying to figure out how to make this happen.

In Touchnote, when you start a postcard you select a picture from camera/gallery/facebook and then it displays it in a ImageView(I think?) and you can pinch zoom it and rotate, etc.

[image]

**Pinch2Zoom**
[image]

Also, after the picture is edited by the user, I want to use that image in another imageview.

How's that achievable?

Comment: They might be using a WebView and some javascript for that. Don't quote me on it though.

Comment: I might be wrong, but I don't think that's the way, as it is a bit odd...

Comment: @silentw, just cause it's odd doesn't make it wrong. Further, if WebView can do this automatically, why would you rewrite the wheel?

Comment: @AedonEtLIRA you are right, but how would I use that image later if using an webview?

Comment: @silentw You could store in a temporary buffer folder on the SDCard?

Comment: @AedonEtLIRA and how can I achieve that? :)

Comment: Are you downloading the image or is it an application image?

Comment: The image is in Uri format (from camera/gallery)

Comment: If that's the case then what's the problem? You already have to get it [the image] once, so you can just grab it again when another view needs it.

Comment: But I want to grab the edited one, the one that the user edits in that activity...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I found this library on github that does the pinch to zoom thingy and stuff:

https://github.com/jasonpolites/gesture-imageview

I'm posting this here so if there's anyone with the same question, they can use this. Yes, it's a bit limited, but it works out :)

Answer (score 1):

If you truly wish to do this using MOSTLY Native Android APIs, then you can implement the ImageView and android's native pinch to zoom capability.  From there you can follow the link I have provided on StackOverflow to grab the drawingCache (essentially a screenshot) of the ImageView to place into another imageview

[android screenshot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6436899/android-screenshot)

Comment: I don't prefer native android APIs, it can use other APIs. I'm here trying to figure out what is the best way, and ofc, how to do it.

Comment: How are you trying to deliver the app, are you trying to deliver it as a web based app, or as a native app?

Comment: I'm trying to deliver it as a native app

Comment: In this case you will do one of two things.  Deliver a native app that does nothing more than bring up a WebView that calls your website containing your web based app of do all of the work directly inside your native app.  I would suggest doing all of the work directly inside the native app, Ive always noticed the functionalities are snappier and more responsive.  That being said my previous answer still should apply!!!